# Google analytics and youtube-videos

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, youtube

I am trying to figure out how to use Google Analytics to track views of a number of youtube-videos on a site.

I have put the following code between within the body-tags.

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I have managed to track clicks on buttons in the following way:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" type="button" class="btn" target="_blank" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'ReadMore', 'clickOnLink', 'Article');">Read more!</a>
```

The site is really simple... It consists of a single page with a number of panels. Each panel has some text and a video. The code looks like this:

```html
<section id="panel-a" class="panel-a">
 <div class="container">

  <!-- Contents -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-left-or-center">
   <h2>Header</h2>
   <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Video -->
  <div class="video">
   <div class="video-container">
    <iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/example123" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</section>


<section id="panel-b" class="panel-b">
 <div class="container">

  <!-- Contents -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-left-or-center">
   <h2>Header</h2>
   <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Video -->
  <div class="video">
   <div class="video-container">
    <iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/example456" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</section>

<section id="panel-c" class="panel-c">
 <div class="container">

  <!-- Contents -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-left-or-center">
   <h2>Header</h2>
   <p>Text</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Video -->
  <div class="video">
   <div class="video-container">
    <iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/example789" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</section>
```

How should I proceed if I want to track whether the videos start, are paused, and finished?

I have looked at this [link](http://nicomiceli.com/youtube-embed-tracking-google-analytics/), but I can't figure out how I should implement it in my code... I new to web development and would appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: This link (https://megalytic.com/blog/tracking-youtube-videos-using-google-analytics) is helpful.

Comment: Hmm... This link describes how it is done if you only have one video on the page, right? There are several videos on my page.